# Как завершить программу при определённом условии?

Tags: c++

Скажем есть калькулятор, который нужно защитить паролем, получается надо использовать ветвление `if (password = 5555)` далее пишем  `else{ exit(0); }` 
вот собственно весь мой код

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main (){
   int password;
cout << "Enter the password" << endl;
cin >> password;
if (password = 555){
    cout << "Welcome to my calculator!" << endl;
} else{
    exit(0);
}
int num_1, num_2, result;
cout << "Enter number 1: " << endl;
cin >> num_1;
cout << "Enter number 2: " << endl;
cin >> num_2;
result = num_1 + num_2;
cout << "Result is " << result << endl;
}
```

Comment: в первом коде надо три пятёрки. я это понимаю это не ошибка а опечатка

Comment: Это просто очепятка начинающего - использовать `=` вместо `==` в `if (password = 555){`...

Comment: Лучше при ненормальном выходе (вряд ли вы считаете ввод неверного пароля нормальным, программа же не работает далее) писать `exit(1);` (код возврата 0 по соглашению оповещает вызывавшую программу (скрипт, шелл) об *успешном* завершении).

Comment: @avp, в C++ лучше использовать `return` из `main()` вместо `exit`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30250934/1418463

Answer (score 0):

Вместо exit(0); напиши return 0;
И в условии if поменяй "=" на "==".

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <vector> 
using namespace std; 
int main () { 
    int password;

    cout << "Enter the password" << endl; 
    cin >> password; 

    if (password == 555) { 
        cout << "Welcome to my calculator!" << endl; 
    } else { 
        return 0;; 
    } 
    int num_1, num_2, result; 
    cout << "Enter number 1: " << endl; 
    cin >> num_1; 
    cout << "Enter number 2: " << endl; 
    cin >> num_2; 
    result = num_1 + num_2; 
    cout << "Result is " << result << endl; 
}
```

Comment: Здесь принято приводить код в виде текста, а не картинок. Поправьте свой ответ